# Google Maps API Drawing Polygon - overlaycomplete event only returns one set of coordinates?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this event listener for when a shape is created:

```js
// This example requires the Drawing library. Include the libraries=drawing
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=drawing">

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -33.872, lng: 151.252},
    zoom: 6
  });

  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
    drawingControl: false,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT,
      drawingModes: []
    },
    polygonOptions: {
      fillColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      clickable: true,
      editable: true,
      zIndex: 1
    }    
  });
  
  drawingManager.setMap(map);
  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the outer path.
  var outerCoords = [
    {lat: -25.364, lng: 155.207}, // north west
    {lat: -35.364, lng: 155.207}, // south west
    {lat: -35.364, lng: 148.207}, // south east
    {lat: -25.364, lng: 148.207}  // north east
  ];


  map.data.add({geometry: new google.maps.Data.Polygon([outerCoords])});
  
  
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
    if(event.type == 'polygon') {
       var verticles = event.overlay.getPaths();
      
      verticles.forEach(function(verticle, ind){
      console.log({
        "index": ind,
        "lat": verticle.getAt(ind).lat(),
        "lng": verticle.getAt(ind).lng(),
        "obj": verticle.getAt(ind)
      });        
      });
    }
  
  
});  
  
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="capture"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBFOolEMjIlnlkVle8gsiDA1ym3aktxEGc&libraries=drawing&callback=initMap"
         async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, .getPaths() seem to return only one set of lat/lng, regardless of how many lines my Polygon consists of. From the documentation it seemed that it should return an array of objects, where each one is an array of two points (lat/lng) needed to draw the line. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
var verticles = event.overlay.getPaths();
```

For this:

```
var verticles = event.overlay.getPath().getArray()
```